# Query a specific GET field?

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

How can I get just a single field (called "name") from an entry in my AppSync/Dynamo table, for a given "id:"? This is instead of getting the entire row of fields for that 'id' returned to me. I only need the single field.

The following doesn't work:

```
const userName = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(GetUsers, { id: "3b342de-34k5-434....." }, "name") );
```

Schema:

```
type Users @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  email: String
}
```

Query:

```
export const getUsers = `query GetUsers($id: ID!) {
  getUsers(id: $id) {
    id
    name
    email
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `GetUser` look like?

Comment: Just updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
export const getUser = `query GetUsers($id: ID!) {
  getUsers(id: $id) {name}
}`

const userName = (await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getUsers, {id: "xxx"}))).getUser.data.name
```

Be aware that the `await` gives you a nested object that includes the `name`. You have to extract it out. Besides, what you really need is `type User`, not `type Users`.

Comment: Hi Yik. Couple of questions. 1) do i need to add the new 'export const getUser...' code you added to my queries.js and 'amplify push'?  2) If i don't use the await, will i get the 'name' directly assigned to my const userName?

Comment: 1. You can either use the existing `getUsers` that returns >= 1 fields, or create a new query to get only 1 field. It is up to you. 
2. use `await` or not doesn't affect the output data structure. You need to do the `.getUser.data.xxx` to get the name. Anyway it is just one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is querying `getUsers` from your graphql server, and is asking for `id`, `name`, and `email`.

If you only want the `name`, change the query to this:

```
query GetUsers($id: ID!) {
  getUsers(id: $id) {
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to push this to Amplify? Or adding this code to my queries.js file is enough?

Comment: Also i need GetUsers elsewhere in my class. I can't "import { getUsers as GetUsers } from './graphql/queries' "   and   "import { getUser as GetUsers } from './graphql/queries' "  in the same file, so this isn't working. Also i get an error saying: Must provide source

Comment: You would push this code to where your query lives.  In this case, your `getUsers` function